# Trying to figure out how to get the standard deviation and mean with numbers aquired from Scanner with Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

This is one of the first assignments I have used with Arrays so I am not exactly sure how this works or if I am doing it correctly. Here is the program currently

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    double[] numbers = new double[9];
    System.out.print("Enter 10 numbers: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    double number = s.nextDouble();
    }

    System.out.println("The mean is " + mean(numbers));
    System.out.println("The standard deviation is : " + deviation(numbers));

}

public static double deviation(double[] x) {
    double mean = mean(x);
    double squareSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        squareSum += Math.pow(x[i] - mean, 2);
    }
    return Math.sqrt((squareSum) / (x.length - 1));
}

public static double mean(double[] x) {
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        sum += x[i];
    }
    return sum / x.length;
}
}
```

What have I done wrong, the output is coming out as 0.0 for both mean and standard deviation

Comment: Time to learn debugging techniques. Either use a debugger or a poor-man's debugger (a bunch of println statements) to find out why your program is misbehaving.

Comment: You don't assign anything to the array. And you won't be able to add 10 numbers to an array of size 9,

Comment: You're getting 0 because your array has nothing but 0s in it.

Comment: how do I put the inputs with the s.nextDouble go into the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you want to put 10 double values in array, you have to define the size of your array (number of elements in the array) to be 10:

  ```
  double[] numbers = new double[10];
  ```
- > how do I put the inputs with the s.nextDouble go into the array?

Instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    double number = s.nextDouble();
}
```

assign the the double values you read into the array as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
   numbers[i] = s.nextDouble();
}
```

And [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) you can read about Java arrays.

Comment: I love you dude, Sorry if it was a basic question but this is my first assignments with Arrays so I hadn't really figured out how they work just yet. Thank you so much mate.